# get and set issues

Tags: c#, accessor

Here is the code that demonstrates my problem (All in the same namespace):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Fubar.BGroup.A = true;
    }

    public Foo Fubar = new Foo();
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
    }

    private BoolGroup bGroup = new BoolGroup();
    public BoolGroup BGroup
    {
        get{ return this.bGroup; }
        set
        { 
            this.bGroup = value;
            this.doSomething();
        }
    }
}

public class BoolGroup
{
    public BoolGroup()
    {
    }

    private bool a;
    public bool A
    {
        get { return this.a; }
        set { this.a = value; }
    }
}

private void doSomething()
{
    ....
}
```

I will never get to doSomething() and I really want to.  What am I doing wrong?  The values will all get set properly, but I never seem to get into that the set part of BGroup.

Thanks

Comment: What language do you refer to?

Comment: you'll get more people to look at it if you put the language in the tags, I assume C#?

Comment: Definitely C#. What other language has all the things we see used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never set `BGroup` at all. The closest things you do are `Fubar.BGroup.A = true` and `bGroup = new BoolGroup();`.
`Fubar.BGroup.A = true` *gets* the `BGroup` property, and sets the `A` property on the `BoolGroup` object, it doesn't set the `BGroup`.
`bGroup = new BoolGroup()` sets the backing field of the `BGroup` property, which is why you get that `BoolGroup` when you get `BGroup`, but it doesn't go through the setter.

If you want to use the setter, your `Foo` class should be like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        // Note uppercase on BGroup to access the property and 
        //   not its backing field.
        BGroup = new BoolGroup(); 
    }

    private BoolGroup bGroup;
    public BoolGroup BGroup
    {
        get{ return this.bGroup; }
        set
        { 
            this.bGroup = value;
            this.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All of the answers solved the problem, but this one explained it the best to me.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you're never setting BGroup.  You're setting A, which is a *property* of BGroup.

Try something like

```
this.Fubar.BGroup = new BoolGroup();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the setter of the BGroup property with this statement:

```
this.Fubar.BGroup.A = true;
```

"this.Fubar.BGroup" calls the getter (returns a BoolGroup) and with ".A = true" you are calling the setter of the A property of BoolGroup.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Fubar.BGroup.A = true;
```

is setting the property A of Fubar.BGroup, it's not setting Fubar.BGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. The reason it isn't triggering is because you aren't actually setting Fubar.BGroup anywhere. You are setting Fubar.BGroup.A in the Form constructor....this won't trigger the doSomething method. You need to do something like:

```
this.Fubar.BGroup = new BGroup();
```

or do it internally in your Foo constructor:

```
public Foo()
{
    this.BGroup = new BGroup();
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is fine, but your second suggestion is basically the same as what he's already doing. Did you mean `this.BGroup = new BGroup();`?

Comment: Sorry yes that was supposed to be the property not the private field I was assigning. I will update.